# Get-Migrations in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

This might be a stupid question, but it does seem the EF Core doesn't have the Get-Migrations command. Was it replaced anyhow or did MS just decide it is not needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're correct: Get-Migrations doesn't seem to be available in Entity Framework Core.

As an alternative, maybe you can use `__EFMigrationsHistory`:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table
>
> By default, EF Core keeps track of which migrations have been applied
>   to the database by recording them in a table named
>   __EFMigrationsHistory.

Comment: I'm aware of that table, it was just sometimes handy to quickly check where my db is at directly from console before applying a migration or after migrating back in a history.

Comment: I'm usually in Visual Studio - I find it quickest/easiest to look at the "Migrations" folder.  You can also `select * from __EFMigrationsHistory`.  ...AND ...`dotnet ef migrations list` is now available.

Answer (score 4):

Diferent from EF in .Net Framework, you can still get the list of migrations from the command `get-migration -context <your_context>`. This command shows you all the migrations you have and even if its been applied to the database yet. Just remember to set you environment before you get the migrations.

Comment: Must have been added lately as it did not exist at the time of writing this question. It also highlights the pending migrations if connection string is provided (`--connection`) what is the main advantage of the EF6 `Get-Migrations` command. Doc is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#listing-migrations

Comment: This command has been on at least since .Net core 3.1.

Comment: Just done a quick check, as a coincidence, this question was written the day when .NET Core (and EF Core) 3.1 was announced :-)